# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/client/fluent/Async$ExecRunnable.class

Tags: android

> Error:Execution failed for task ':project:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/client/fluent/Async$ExecRunnable.class

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a read of [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! Add the code you tried to your question

Comment: Post your build.gradle